# Left Alt + Shift + 0: Cannot change language in Emacs/VcXsrv

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the Emacs text editor using WSL + VcXsrv on Windows 10. When typing texts, I need to change the language all the time, using combinations such as:

- <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>: German
- <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>: English
- <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>: Spanish
- <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>: Greek

*How do I make these key combinations work in VcXsrv?*

Comment: Configured them in Windows. I now realized that one needs to configure input languages separately for the XvXsrv, like for an XServer running under Linux. Installing Windows Emacs via Chocolatey now...

Comment: Found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/how-to-switch-keyboard-layouts-for-different-languages). Windows side language will not applied in WSL GUI programs.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. I want to have the language that I select in Windows to be available in Emacs/VcXsrv. That *this is not possible* would I think be the correct answer, simple.

Comment: @Biswapriyo On second thought, the method of changing the input method directly in Emacs using `toggle-input-method` as [linked](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/how-to-switch-keyboard-layouts-for-different-languages) by you *is* possibly the best workaround. Consider turning it into an answer. (specific to Emacs, of course, but that's what I'm using)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (WSL1) + VcXsrv on Windows 10 and to change keyboard layout in my X apps, I run the following command in Ubuntu before starting my app

```
setxkbmap us,ru -option grp:ctrl_shift_toggle
```

This allows me to change layout between English and Russian with Ctrl+Shift in X apps. Layout change happens in Windows is well, since same key combination is set there. List of possible layouts and options is [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html), although I don't see there your desired combination Alt + Shift + Number.